# Rewrite $\Gamma(-z)$ in terms of $\Gamma(z)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functions, special-functions

Is it possible to rewrite $\Gamma(-z)$ in terms of $\Gamma(z)$ where $\Gamma(z) = \int^\infty_0 t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [Euler's reflection formula:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula), which, together with the functional equation for Gamma ($\Gamma(t+1) = t \Gamma(t)$) gives you want you want.

Comment: Thank you. Just to check with you: $\Gamma(-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi (1+z) \Gamma (1+z)} = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi (1+z) }.\frac{1}{z\Gamma (z)}$ ?

Answer (score 5):

We have that $\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)$, or $\Gamma(1-z)=-z\Gamma(-z)$.
We also have that $\Gamma(1-z)\Gamma(z)=\dfrac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$.
Putting these two together yields $$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(-z)=-\dfrac{\pi}{z\sin(\pi z)}$$