# Integral of the product of the Gamma function and the Confluent Hypergeometric function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

This question was [posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80189/inverting-the-fourier-transform-for-a-fisher-distribution) previously on stats.SE.

The characteristic function of the [Fisher$(1,\alpha)$ distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) is:
$$C(t)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha +1}{2}\right) U\left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{\alpha }{2},-i t \alpha \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}$$

What is the Fourier transform, $\mathcal {F} _ {t,x}^{-1}$ , of $\lim_{n \to \infty} (C(t))^n$
Where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function. I did some simplification in the hope of making things simpler:

$$C(t) = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\right) U\left(\frac{1}{2},1-\frac{\alpha }{2},-i t \alpha \right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)}$$
$$= \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) }{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \Gamma \left( 1 -\frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}.\int^1_0 e^{-i t^2} t^{-\frac{1}{2}}  (1-t)^{-\frac{\alpha }{2}-\frac{1}{2}}dt \;\;(1)$$
Using the properties of the gamma function and this post here `

> [Rewrite $\Gamma(-z)$ in terms of $\Gamma(z)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634326/rewrite-gamma-z-in-terms-of-gammaz/634327?noredirect=1#comment1337354_634327)

I was able to simplify (If my math is correct) , 
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha}{2}+ \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) }{\Gamma \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right) \Gamma \left( 1 -\frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)} = \frac{-2 *\pi * \sin(\pi(1+\alpha)) (\Gamma \left( \alpha \right) )^2}{\sin(\pi(1+\frac{\alpha}{2}))}$$
Combining this with (1), We get a product of the gamma function with the integral in (1). Any ideas?